# I don't know how to use console line on linux

Tags: command-line, usb, tty, serial-port

I'm a student and I need to use a console cable to connect a Cisco switch

but i don't know how to use it in linux

Below is my device information：

```
Linux xianyu-ThinkBook-14-G4-IAP 5.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 23:42:32 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[image]
I bought this cable from online

I don't know where this device is mounted and how to use it when I connect the data cable to my computer.

The output of `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 5986:2146 Acer, Inc Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter   ##This is the console line
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It is correctly recognized by the system but I don't know how to use it

Related output from `dmesg` command:

```
[ 4646.787367] usb 3-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 4646.788584] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 4646.788631] ch341 3-1:1.0: device disconnected
[ 4702.215967] userif-3: sent link down event.
[ 4702.215979] userif-3: sent link up event.
[ 4703.777825] userif-3: sent link down event.
[ 4703.777836] userif-3: sent link up event.
[ 4866.734994] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 4868.741206] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 4868.890410] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.54
[ 4868.890424] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4868.890429] usb 3-1: Product: USB2.0-Ser!
[ 4868.892214] ch341 3-1:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 4868.892649] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: break control not supported, using simulated break
[ 4868.892805] usb 3-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 4869.449395] input: BRLTTY 6.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input36
[ 4869.451629] usb 3-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 4869.452520] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 4869.452549] ch341 3-1:1.0: device disconnected
```

I don't know what is the file path of the console line so can't use it.

I tried to find `ttyUSB0` in `/dev` , but couldn't find it.

I have two guesses：

> This console cable does not work on linux

> I did not find the correct location for this device

Has anyone successfully used the console cable on linux?
Or how to correctly find the file path of the usb device？

Comment: You should look at the Cisco manuals for the switch in question and/or contact Cisco technical support for help.  You don't need to use Linux/Ubuntu.  If it's easier, you might want to use a Windows machine to connect up to the Cisco device instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### General answer

You are almost there ... You have already used `dmesg` to identify the device(port) of your connected serial device i.e `ttyUSB0`:

> `usb 3-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0`

that should be under the `/dev/` directory ... i.e. `/dev/ttyUSB0` ... all there is left for you to accomplish your goal is to connect to it with a screen manager like [screen](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/screen.1.html) ... so, first, install `screen` like so:

```
sudo apt install screen
```

then, connect to the device(port) like so:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0
```

#### Case(yours) specific requirement

That said, however, there is an issue in your case that has to be resolved first. These tow log lines(in your `dmesg` output):

> `usb 3-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1`
>
> `ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0`

indicate that [brltty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/brltty.1.html) daemon/process is enabled and running in the background. Not sure why as it should be disabled by default like the rest of the accessibility features and should only be enabled when the user chooses so and not sure why that device is picked up as a braille device.

> **brltty**  is a background process (daemon) which provides access to the
> console screen (when in text mode) for a blind person using a
> refreshable  braille  display.   It  drives  the braille   display,
> and  provides  complete  screen  review  functionality.   Some  speech
> capability has also been incorporated.

`brltty` interferes and causes the [ch341 USB chip](http://www.anok.ceti.pl/download/ch341ds1.pdf) driver/module to claim(takes over) your device (on brltty's behalf) immediately after connecting your device thus disconnecting your device before you have the chance to use it (it will only appear very briefly under `/dev/` then disappear) ... meanwhile, `brltty` uses its rules file under `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/` for that purpose ... so you can disable this behavior in **three ways** listed below.

**First way:**

by linking(redirecting) that `brltty` udev rules file to `/dev/null` so the rules will never be saved and that file will always be empty *(This will destroy the existing `brltty` rules file and cause the loss of any existing rules in it ... so, back it up first if you think you might need it later)*:

```
sudo find /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/ -type f -iname '*brltty*' -exec ln -sf /dev/null {} \;
```

then, reload the `udev` rules like so:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

**Second way:**

`brltty` can be stopped, disabled and masked as a service like so:

```
sudo systemctl stop brltty.service && \
sudo systemctl disable brltty.service && \
sudo systemctl mask brltty.service
```

then, reboot your machine.

**Third way:**

`brltty` can be totally removed from the system like so:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt remove brltty
```

Comment: I have tried this method. But there is no such device in the /dev .

Comment: I confirmed the output using the dmesg command again after connecting the device, and  I also tried to find the files in the /dev , but did not find this device. But I'll have to try again when I get back to school next week though. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: the device was taken over by `usb 3-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 4869.452520] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0 
[ 4869.452549] ch341 3-1:1.0: device disconnected` brltty, so I understand the message.

Comment: @nobody **Nice catch** .... that should be disabled by default ... isn't it? OK updating answer ... thanks buddy.

Comment: It is indeed the problem caused by brltty.....I tried disable brltty but it didn't work, so I just removed it. Now I can use it!