# /dev/ttyUSB on Ubuntu 22.04 with wayland

Tags: 22.04

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.  I can no longer see any /dev/ttyUSB*.  I am trying to use the Arduino IDE to program an ESP32.  I had no problems before the upgrade.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check `brltty` in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414463/968501) ... Although a different device, but could be the same issue.

Comment: Yes after removing brltty and rebooting it now works. Thanks Bill.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I don't know how to use console line on linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414463/i-dont-know-how-to-use-console-line-on-linux)